# autofac multiple services (same interface - multiple addons providing it) how to implement?

Tags: c#, service, autofac

I have a service interface, lets say IAddonServiceX which is implemented by many, but not all addons to a system. I want to have an IEnumerable so that I could iterate and execute methods for every addon that registered this service? Ho can this be done with autofac?

Comment: What have you tried? Autofac has implicit support for it, so you just need register the implementation with `builder.RegisterType<Impl1>.As<IAddonServiceX>(); builder.RegisterType<Impl2>.As<IAddonServiceX>()...`, and where you want to use it you just depend on `IEnumberable<IAddonServiceX >`...

Comment: Is it not true that builder.RegisterType<Impl2>.As<IAddonServiceX>() overrides the registration builder.RegisterType<Impl1>.As<IAddonServiceX>();? 

so I can't have access to both of them?

Comment: It only overrides which the default instance if you write `container.Resolve<IAddonServiceX>` you will get `Impl2` but if you write `container.Resolve<IEnumberable<IAddonServiceX>>` you will get back both Impl1 and Impl2

Comment: Ok this is it, may you post it as answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autofac [has implicit support for it](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b), so you just need register your implementations with

```
builder.RegisterType<Impl1>.As<IAddonServiceX>();    
builder.RegisterType<Impl2>.As<IAddonServiceX>();
```

And when you are resolving an `IEnumerable<IAddonServiceX>` with  `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IAddonServiceX>>` or using `IEnumerable<IAddonServiceX>` in your constructor then Autofac will provide you all the implementations.

Comment: Nice :) the link you have provided is broken though :|